How can I stretch my model's leg without scaling it?
I want to stretch my model's leg without it getting bigger.

When I move the Heel IK down, the leg stretches, which I don't mind, but the leg also gets bigger, which I don't want to happen. Below is my desired effect:

As you can see, the leg still stretches but stays the same size. This is what I want to achieve. How can I do this?
Here is my .blend file if this helps.    
